# How to make a var in a click function be globally available

Tags: jquery, variables, scope, onclick, global-variables

I have two click events, one is triggering a page transition

```
  $('.pt-trigger').click(function() {
      $pageTrigger = $(this);
      // e.preventDefault();
      setTimeout(function() { Animate($pageTrigger); }, delay);
    });
```

and the other animates a carousel

```
$('.carousel .item').click(function(e) {
        var index = $(this).index('li');
        carousel.cycleActiveTo(index);
        e.preventDefault();


        if (currentIndex != index) {
            var difference;

            if (currentIndex == 0 && index >= 5) {
                difference = (index - currentIndex) - 13;
            } else {
                difference = index - currentIndex;
            }

            difference = Math.abs(difference);
            delay = difference * options.duration;
            currentIndex = index;

            setTimeout(goToLink, delay);
            // console.log(delay);
        } else {
            // Animate();
        }
    });
```

i cannot manage to make the **delay** variable which is generated in the carousel click event, be accessible to the page transition click event.

Basically I just need to time these two things together, is there a better way to do it than I'm doing?

this is the website - http://stfn.herokuapp.com/
and the lines of code snippets above are 403 and 1033

Comment: What's wrong with declaring `var delay` outside the click handlers? - also notice you are updating `window.delay` but using `delay` in the `setTimeout(...)` - these two are not the same

Comment: On to the next question, can you expand on your "need to time these two things together" ? - I am not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish (but using `timeouts` to chain events is usually the wrong approach)

Comment: i see that you are using an `options` object to set the `options.duration`. why not add the delay as property to your option `options.delay`. this would be clear.

Comment: ochi, declaring delay outside the click handler wouldn't work since the delay  time is unique to each element that's being clicked on

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
// define delay in global scope
// delay needs a default value, in case a pt-trigger is clicked before
// using the slider, change 1000 to suit your needs.
var delay = 1000;

// line 403
$('.pt-trigger').click(function() {
    $pageTrigger = $(this);
    // e.preventDefault();
    // console.log('read delay', delay);
    setTimeout(function() { Animate($pageTrigger); }, delay);
});

// line 1033
$('.carousel .item').click(function(e) {
    var index = $(this).index('li');
    carousel.cycleActiveTo(index);
    e.preventDefault();


    if (currentIndex != index) {
        var difference;

        if (currentIndex == 0 && index >= 5) {
            difference = (index - currentIndex) - 13;
        } else {
            difference = index - currentIndex;
        }

        difference = Math.abs(difference);
        delay = difference * options.duration;
        // console.log('set delay', delay);
        currentIndex = index;

        setTimeout(goToLink, delay);
    } else {
        // Animate();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried that already, but for some reason the transition function doesn't catch the delay results

Comment: put a `console.log` after the line where you set the delay, and check its getting set. also add a `console.log` just before you read delay to see if its been set.

Comment: `delay` doesn't have a default value. so if you click a link before the slider has had a chance to set it. it won't work. needs a default value adding like `var delay = 1000;` or something for default case of clicking a link without using slider first. make sense?

Comment: Thanks Phil. Your suggestion works, but then the delay is always 1000, Ideally it should be unique to each click.. I rearranged my code and placed the slider function above the transition function, but still the the click event of the transition (line 625) gets executed before the slider (line 169)
P.S. uploaded latest version of code to heroku

Comment: "slider function above the transition function" its not position in code that counts. its execution order :/. `delay` is being read before its set, so it needs a sensible default. if you have default, and then slide, then click... is it still 1000?

Comment: I set the default to 2000 but yeah its still acting the same https://s23.postimg.org/xkslzzt1n/Screen_Shot_2017_01_07_at_15_16_47.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132569/discussion-between-jurgis-lietunovas-and-phil-poore).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about jquery. But if yplain js, try having a uniquely named global variable, have setter and getter access. Set in the function linked to carousel event and then get in teh page-transition event.

Something like:

```
var carouselTransitionDelay;

function setCarouselTransitionDelay(delay) {
    carouselTransitionDelay=delay;
}

function getCarouselTransitionDelay(){
    return carouselTransitionDelay;
}
```

Comment: Do i have to call the setCarouselTransitionDelay() function somehwere in the code?

Comment: Yes. You need to call set in the click function linked to carousel. And then fetch the value using the get in the transition method. (The method name I wrote was incorrect but Phill has corrected it.)